# Change specific element in list in the simplest way

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Basically, what I do is

```
for (var i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++){
    if (someList[i] == x){
    someList[i] = y;
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure there should be one-liner for such operation. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
In my case there is only element that should be changed, that was stated in the topic.
Presented code changes all instances and that's what I don't like about it. It's an overhead, that's why I asked about simplification.

About array/list selection - let's consider that's it's about List (changed topic). Sorry for misleading information.

Comment: I don't think there is a one-liner for this.

Comment: Can´t think of a one-liner, but a two-liner given that x and y are different: Use Array.IndexOf in a loop... (the check if x and y are different would require a third line again)

Comment: @deviantfan IndexOf wouldn't handle the case when there are more "y"-s in the array.

Comment: You could make a one-liner that returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` (`someList.Select(i => i == x ? y : i)`), but I don't think there's a one-liner to mutate the existing array.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási That´s why I wrote "loop"

Comment: A `for`-loop is made for such things. Why do you want to use  something different? Also, if it's an array, why do you use `someList.Count`?

Comment: Do you want to change a _specific element_? Or change all instances of a _specific value_? Your question says one thing, while the code shows the other. In any case, what is the _problem statement_ here? I.e. what code have you written, what does that code do, and how is that different from what you want it to do?

Comment: @PeterDuniho based on the way the code currently reads, probably every instance.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: ...and based on the way the other text in the question reads, probably just a specific element. Unless you are the OP, you in fact actually don't _know_ which it is. That's my point, which you seem to have missed. A good question makes crystal clear what the goal is; this question is not that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one-liners, you can always use [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  The only modification to have your loop only replace the first element is to use the `break` keyword (which kicks out of the loop).  This is the extension method definition of your method:

```
public static void ReplaceFirst<T> (this List<T> list, T x, T y)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++){
        if (Equals(list[i], x)){
        list[i] = y;
            break; //this stops the loop from further execution
        }
    } 
}
```

You call it like this:

```
list.ReplaceFirst(2, 5555555);
```

A [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NOo0yC)

Comment: Thanks, that's something useful.
I am not sure if I want to use `break` in my case - data can be changed and it's hard to predict should I keep code faster or broader. Anyway, extension methods are the answer.

Comment: Maybe you could use the IList<T> so one can use it with arrays too,

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
someList = someList.Select(i => i == x ? y : i).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

Per your edit, this code will change every element in the array that is equal to `x`

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
var listResult = someList.ToList().ForEach(i => i = i == x ? y : i);
```

Okay, so I cheated a bit with the ternary operator but it's a one liner! Be sure to add `System.Linq` to your usings.

Comment: I don't like it personally, I would surely have to think for a few moments about what it does :) Not worth I think.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási But no one asked for a readable solution. OP has that already. OP asked for a one-liner. (+1)

Comment: This just overwrites the parameter to the lambda. It never writes to the array. Try it -- the array is left unmodified.

Comment: Now it does not even compile since `List.ForEach` is a void method. Who upvotes this? It's so wrong. Creating  a new collection to be able to use `List.ForEach` , use that to modify a lambda which does not change the original reference. So even if `ToList()` wouldn't create a completely different collection this could not work.

Comment: This answer should be removed, it's wrong in every possible way. No offense @beautifulcoder

Answer (score -1):

In case when it's guaranteed that there is at most one "x" in the array, you could write something like this:

```
var i = Array.IndexOf(array, x);
if (i >= 0) array[i] = y;
```

But if you can have more "x" elements and you want to change all, then there is no shorter version I think, or at least it wouldn't be too clean and readable. For example forcing some LINQ magic here would be a complete overkill here IMHO. The for loop is the most readable and clean way.